# How to open a new window in Windows Forms in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have an application that among other things has an Edit Button and when the user clicks on that button I want a new window to open with various textboxes for editing purposes.

I can create a new window with code like

```
Form editform = new Form();
```

But I want to design that window in the Designer too.

Comment: It's trivial but that isn't a reason to close it. If one beginner programmer came here to ask this question, others will too (And find this one, hopefully).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In Visual Studio, right-click on your project and select Add->Windows Form. That will give you a new form to work with. Lay it out how you want. Then you can launch the window from your main window with code similar to the following:

```
MyEditForm form = new MyEditForm();
form.Show();
```

Comment: I also want to add check out the DialogResult to return whether edit was successful, etc.

Comment: Opening it in a non-modal way?

Comment: @PeterMortensen `Show()` is not modal; for a modal dialog you'd want to call the `ShowDialog()` method instead.

Answer (score 6):

To answer Rick's comment on Brian's answer:

```
        using (var login = new Login())
        {
            switch(login.ShowDialog())
            {
                case DialogResult.OK:
                    Application.Run(new Studio());
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Would that be behaving like a modal dialog, then?