# Open an empty page by clicking on menu item

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I'm working on a .NET project and C#. I have to add a button which will open an empty page in the heavy client.
I've never used C# before and I can not find what I'm looking for on the web (perhaps I'm doing wrong)...

So I've already add the button in the menu from the designer view and this code just appear in the code file related to the designer view :

```
private void customizeCVaultImportRulesToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Does anyone know what I'm supposed to write to open an empty page in the same window?
Thanks !

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to open a new window in Windows Forms in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099217/how-to-open-a-new-window-in-windows-forms-in-net)

Comment: Thanks it's almost that !
I've done this :
Form form = new Form();
form.Show();

But it open a new window (like a popup) and I want to stay in the same window. Sorry my english could be wrong, I do not know you see what I mean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a new Form and have the button click event show it, or (I think this is more common) you could just add a panel from the toolbox into the existing form, add all the controls you like to it, and make it invisible, but set it to .Show() on button click.  One advantage using a Panel instead of a new Form is that all of your Form1 properties and methods remain available to you.  That is, if you want them available.  But normally I would use the Panel.

Comment: Ok I see what you mean. I'm doing it ! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Actually when I use Show() method, it opens me a new window plus, the one I already have. To be clear, I want to change the current content of the current window (does not matter what it contains) to replace it by an empty content. Which is gonna contain a table.

Comment: I understand.  But normally they make the new panel the exact same size as the existing Form so it would appear to have changed from one window to another.  There are many ways you can do it.  This one is just the one I usually use.

Comment: The panel won't obscure the existing controls on the form, but it will make its own controls visible.  So to make this all as easy as possible for you, now that I think about it, you should put no controls directly on the form.  Instead, make one panel that is visible when you run the program, and put another panel that you make visible (and the first panel invisible) when you make your menu selection.

Comment: Perhaps I did not get how to do it. I just start .NET and C# this morning.
To sum it up, I have the main window (the one you see when you run the app and which contains the main menu) which contains a lot of elements which appear according to the specifics contents you want to see. Is it from the main window that I have to add the panel?

Comment: Actually when I add a panel (I tried with a blue rectangle that I set visible or not by clicking on the menu that I've add) I have a lot errors when I want to see a different content. I probably did something wrong because it is not working as it should.

Comment: No, I forgot that detail until a minute ago.  Make your blank project.  Pull one panel into the project and dock it in the form.  Put your main controls on it.  Then pull another panel into the form and dock it as well.  Also make its visible property be false (so it will not show when you start the program).  Put that panel's controls on it.  Now with your menu selection, put in the method the line Panel1.Hide(); and Panel2.Show();  Then make a different method to reverse that when you make that menu selection.

Comment: Do you want me to put a basic project on Dropbox for you?  So you can see what I mean?

Comment: Sorry, falling asleep here at the desk, but this should give you a basic idea.  https://www.dropbox.com/s/6oqefsa47iz83gs/Panel.zip?dl=0

Comment: It just is 2 panels, one button in each panel.  When you click one button, it switches which panel is visible (including the button mounted in that panel).  A word of warning, it is possible to accidentally get one panel inside another (as a child to the other panel).  No worries, press CTRL-ALT-T and you will see an outline.  If one panel is inside the other, drag it out in the outline to be at the same level in the outline as the other.  Then toggling between 2 panels or even among more should be easy

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6oqefsa47iz83gs/Panel.zip?dl=0  Sorry, I should have put more controls on there to make the difference more obvious.  I just added a richtextbox to one panel.  Here is a new link.

Comment: Man, this is really awesome !
It helps me a lot !
The CTRL-ALT-T made my day ! Ahah
Thank you so much !